# Problema para hacer funcionar evento 'change' en select

Tags: php, jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente SELECT:

```
<select id="municipio" class="celda corto">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled"><?= $rows['municipio'] ?></option>
    <option>Veracruz</option>
    <option>Boca del Rio</option>
</select>
```

Lo que busco es que aparezca por default (sea visible antes de seleccionar nada) la opcion que se obtiene de la base de datos, pero con esta linea:

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled"><?= $rows['municipio'] ?></option>
```

deja de funcionar mi evento:

```
$('#municipio').on('change', function() {
    alert('Prueba');
});
```

¿De que manera lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Lanza algún error en consola?

Comment: ¿Y por qué `disabled`?

Comment: No lanza error en consola, y el _disabled_ es porque los campos de la BD pueden estar vacios, y para que no permita elegir el campo vacio y tenga que elegir una de las otras opciones.

Comment: Tenes un error de concepto. Si el campo esta disabled no se puede seleccionar. Si querés que se pueda seleccionar, saca el disabled y crea un js que te obligue a tener un valor valido en el select antes de enviar el form

Comment: Por otro lado asegurate que tu función esté dentro de $(document).ready(function(){ <ACA> });  para asegurarte que el html esta cargado cuando corre tu funcion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu comentario, si la consulta te regresa campos vacios deberías de filtrarlos con un where, estaría bien si pones la consulta.

```
SELECT CAMPO_ID, TRIM(CAMPO_NOMBRE) FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPO_NOMBRE <> ""
```

En tu script inténtalo de la siguiente forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change','#municipio',function(){
  alert('Prueba');
  });
})
```

Comment: Wow, esto me ha funcionado, pero no entiendo, cual es la diferencia entre esto:  `$('#municipio').on('change', function() {
  alert('Prueba');
 });` y esto:  `$(document).on('change','#municipio',function(){
   alert('Prueba');
   });` ¿no es lo mismo?

Comment: Mirate este artículo, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820906/what-is-different-between-document-on-and-element-on. Si te sirvió mi respuesta no olvides marcarla como correcta en la palomita :)

Comment: a ver si he entendido bien, de esta forma `$(document).on('change','selector',function(){})` lo que hace es que el evento se _delega_ al selector y todos sus hijos?... Si gracias, ya te pongo la palomita.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es darle el value correspondiente

```
<select id="municipio" class="celda corto">
    <option selected="true" value="<?php echo $rows['municipio'] ?>" disabled="disabled"><?php echo $rows['municipio'] ?></option>
    <option value="Veracruz">Veracruz</option>
    <option value="Boca del Rio">Boca del Rio</option>
</select>
```

Y despues haces la siguiente prueba

```
$('#municipio').on('change', function() {
    var municipio = $(this).val();
    alert(municipio );
});
```

has la prueba y espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias cargarlo asi :

```
<select id="municipio" class="celda corto">
    <? if ($rows['municipio'] != "") { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['municipio'];?>'" selected="true"><?= $rows['municipio'] ?></option>
    <? } ?>
    <option value="Veracruz">Veracruz</option>
    <option value="Boca del Rio">Boca del Rio</option>
</select>
```

Si viene el valor de la base de datos, agrega el `<option>` seleccionado y con el valor. Si no, agrega las demas opciones al selector y ademas, te faltaba agregar el atributo `value` en los `<options>` para cuando cuando utilices el valor po puedes rescatar.